# Какое согласовение будет правильным в данном предложении и почему?

Tags: согласование

Курение и продажа табачных изделий на территории гостиницы запрещены/а.

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь.

При **прямом порядке слов** (сказуемое следует за однородными подлежащими) обычно употребляется форма **множественного числа** сказуемого, ( зависит от **формы связи** между однородными подлежащими), особенно если **однородные подлежащие связаны соединительными союзами и**, да или только интонацией.

Например:

а) Жара и засуха стояли более трех недель (Л. Толстой)

Указанные положения не носят категорического характера, постпозитивное сказуемое может стоять в форме единственного числа

Форма единственного числа сказуемою предпочитается при смысловой близости однородных подлежащих, например:
сказуемое следует за подлежащим:

С зимой холодной нужда, голод настает (Крылов); Неточность и запутанность выражений свидетельствует только о запутанности мыслей (Чернышевский); Эта простота и ясность мышления заключает в себе задатки новой жизни… (Добролюбов); Никто и ничто не нарушало тишины.

Ср. также: выписка и выдача документов производится (общая операция) — прием и выдача книг производятся **(разные операции)**.

На согласование сказуемого может оказать влияние наличие среди подлежащих формы множественного числа: В постель ее уложили ревность и слезы (Чехов). Но и в этом случае возможна форма единственного числа сказуемого: Несся тяжелый топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги (Серафимович).
Источник:
http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-190-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-odnorodnymi-podlezhashchimi

Пример из НКРЯ:

С 1634 года курение и продажа табака были строго запрещены, но процесс тотальной табакотизации России было уже не остановить. [Александр МЕШКОВ. Как царь Петр русский народ на табак подсадил // Комсомольская правда,

Ваш пример:

Курение и продажа табачных изделий на территории гостиницы запрещены.

Причины выбора указаны жирным шрифтом.